# Multiple collada scenes

Tags: webgl, three.js

I have two collada files (two different scenes: "01.dae" and "02.dae").
I want to display 01.dae first and right after the animation finishes I want to load and display 02.dae on the same canvas.
(I'm trying to modify "webgl_loader_collada_keyframe.html" to do this but no results so far.)

How could I handle more than one animated collada scenes? A source code or any tips or tricks would be appreciated!

---

Thank you for your answer. I modified my code based on your idae but unfortunately it's not working.
Could you take a look at my code please?

Here is my code:

```
    loader.load( 'pump.dae', function ( collada ) {


        model = collada.scene;
        animations = collada.animations;
        kfAnimationsLength = animations.length;
        model.scale.x = model.scale.y = model.scale.z = 0.125; // 1/8 scale, modeled in cm

        init();
        start();
        animate( lastTimestamp );
        setTimeout(loadSecond,3000);                
    } );


    function loadSecond()
    {           
    loader2.load( 'pump2.dae', function ( collada2 ) 
    {

        scene.remove( model );              
        model2 = collada2.scene;
        animations2 = collada2.animations;
        kfAnimationsLength2 = animations2.length;
        model2.scale.x = model2.scale.y = model2.scale.z = 0.125; // 1/8 scale, modeled in cm

        init2();
        start2();
        animate2( lastTimestamp2 );

        //alert("second loaded");

    } );
    }
```

...

As you can see I extended your code with

scene.remove( model );

to remove the previous scene.

The first scene displays and then disapears properly however the new secene does not load. Do you have an idae why?

(Note: I don't know how long my first scene realy is.)

Answer (score 0):

If you know how long the animation is, you could use a setTimeout to load the second model.

```
var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
loader.options.convertUpAxis = true;
loader.load('PATH TO MODEL', function colladaReady( collada){
    dae = collada.scene;
    skin = collada.skins[ 0 ];              
    dae.scale.x = dae.scale.y = dae.scale.z = 1;
    dae.updateMatrix();
    scene.add(dae);    
    render(); 
    setTimeout(loadSecond,3000);
});

function loadSecond(){
    var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
    loader.options.convertUpAxis = true;
    loader.load('PATH TO MODEL', function colladaReady( collada){
        ///repeat model loading logic
}
```

Where the time interval in the setTimeout is equal to the length of your animation.

Comment: can you add more of your code? From what's there it looks like you may be running into some javascript variable scope issues and duplicating some functions that you don't need to duplicate. For instance, I would think that you only need to run init() once, and outside of the loader function for that matter. Also, you can initiate the loader each time you need it if you get the scope correct.

Comment: My code is a bit long (but easy to understand). That's why I uploaded it here:
http://uploading.com/files/get/bec7a142/two_scenes.html
Could you take a look at it please?!
You should start the timer and wait 30s to start the download. Thanks!

Comment: I took a quick look at the code. I think the problem stems from the fact that you are creating two Scenes. You should just have one init() function and at the bottom of that function, you should run the code that loads the first model and runs the animation. Then set the timer and call a function to remove the first model, load the second model and run that animation. No need to make a new scene or anything, just load the model and add it to the original scene. If that doesn't clear things up, let me know and I'll do a code outline for you.

Comment: Last week I tried several times to load my second scene. Without any results. I tried everything but instead of the second scene I always got a black screen.
How to load the second scene and run the animation?

Comment: Shadill, I'm senceless after several tries. Could you please send me a code outline you had mentioned earlier?